# Insert/delete wxDataViewColumn after performing reorder column in wxDataViewCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I did columns reordering in `wxDataViewCtrl`. I inserted a new column using `InsertColumn()` API.

I got the following assert failure:

```
---------------------------
wxWidgets Debug Alert
---------------------------
..\..\src\msw\headerctrl.cpp(442): assert "order >= 0 && order <= GetShownColumnsCount()" failed in wxHeaderCtrl::MSWToNativeOrder(): logic error

Call stack:
[00] wxHeaderCtrl::DoInsertItem                 f:\cwscode\tools\source\wxwidgets-3.0\src\msw\headerctrl.cpp:347
[01] wxHeaderCtrl::DoSetCount                   f:\cwscode\tools\source\wxwidgets-3.0\src\msw\headerctrl.cpp:218
[02] wxHeaderCtrlBase::SetColumnCount           f:\cwscode\tools\source\wxwidgets-3.0\src\common\headerctrlcmn.cpp:108
[03] wxDataViewCtrl::OnColumnsCountChanged      f:\cwscode\tools\source\wxwidgets-3.0\src\generic\datavgen.cpp:4766
[04] wxDataViewCtrl::InsertColumn               f:\cwscode\tools\source\wxwidgets-3.0\src\generic\datavgen.cpp:4750

Do you want to stop the program?
You can also choose [Cancel] to suppress further warnings.
---------------------------
Yes   No   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

The same is true with `DeleteColumn()` API too, not working after reordering column.

What is this **logic error** and most important my all reordering changes back to original column orders.
I want to allow the user to perform reorder/add/delete columns, but after reordering add/delete not working at all.

Comment: Either you used wrong indices in your code or you found a bug in wxDVC itself. If you think it's the latter, you should provide a way of reproducing it and open bug report in [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org)

Comment: This is bug with wxDVC, same I can reproduce in wxWidgets dataview sample as well.

Comment: wxTrac requires login first. But after registration, I am not getting "Account verification email" to my registered email id.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. The problem is probably at your ISP/email provider level, wxTrac email notifications do work.

Comment: Still not able to verify my email, hence can not log the bug. But definitely, it's a bug. Can someone log it and can provide me the bug token. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it. Try contacting wxTrac admin by mail.